# How to use multiple storyboards defined in assemblies?

Tags: swift, typhoon

I'm using different storyboards for different use-cases. My question is how can I instantiate a storyboard, a view controller by it's storyboard identifier and connect it to the actual viewcontroller class?

Here's where I am right now:

```
public dynamic func loadingViewController() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(LoadingViewController.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.injectProperty("presenter", with: self.loadingPresenter())
    }

//        return TyphoonDefinition.withFactory(self.storyboard(), selector: "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:") {
//            (factory) in
//            
//            factory.injectParameterWith("LoadingViewController")
//            
//        }
}

public dynamic func storyboard() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TyphoonStoryboard.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.useInitializer("storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:") {
            (initializer) in

            initializer.injectParameterWith("Loading")
            initializer.injectParameterWith(self)
            initializer.injectParameterWith(NSBundle.mainBundle())
        }

        definition.scope = TyphoonScope.Singleton
    }
}
```

In this example the storyboard's name is 'Loading', the viewcontroller is 'LoadingViewController' and the storyboard identifier is also 'LoadingViewController'.

Any help (or example code) would be appreciated!

Comment: This is how the storyboard looks like: [Storyboard](http://home.sch.bme.hu/~abicska/upload/typhoon_2.png) and this is what the running app looks like: [App](http://home.sch.bme.hu/~abicska/upload/typhoon_1.png). So actually the 'LoadingViewController' won't get loaded. I don't really know where should I call the 'storyboard()' function mentioned above.

Comment: Actually I can't find where is the problem, as you can see the storyboard gets loaded and the navigation controller is presented, but the navigation controller's rootViewController is not set, as far as I can see

Comment: @JasperBlues okay so I went through a sample code again. Could you tell me how may I set class definition's factory to the storyboard? Because the 'definition.factory' param is long gone. The example code is based on Typhoon 2 and they wrote something like this: `definition.factory = [storyboard definition]` Thank you

Comment: OK shown below. `definition.factory` is deprecated, but I thought it would still work. In any case, methods below are neater. . . did the answer address your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a TyphoonDefinition representing a UIViewController that will be emitted from a storyboard:

**Create a definition for the storyboard:**

```
- (UIStoryboard *)storyboard
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[TyphoonStoryboard class] 
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition useInitializer:@selector(storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:)
            parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                [initializer injectParameterWith:@"StoryboardName"];
                [initializer injectParameterWith:self];
                [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            }];
    }];
}
```

**If you'd like to instantiate the controller marked as the 'initial' controller in the storyboard:**

```
- (UIViewController *)initialControllerFromStoryBoard
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withFactory:[self storyboard] 
        selector:@selector(instantiateInitialViewController)];
}
```

**If you'd like to instantiate another controller in the storyboard:**

```
- (UIViewController *)arbitraryControllerFromStoryboard
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withFactory:[self storyboard] 
        selector:@selector(instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:)

        parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *factoryMethod) {
            [factoryMethod injectParameterWith:@"ViewControllerId"];
        }];
}
```

Sorry for replying in Objective-C, but I haven't got my Swift chops on at the moment.